# How do I partially update a field in MongoDB so the new field will replace the old text to exisiting record

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

This is the field
logo
"https://image.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/game/163221197…"

"image.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com" this part I want to change to "cloudfront.net" because I need to update all the logo from S3 to cloudfont.

Comment: [`"$replaceOne"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input document looks something like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  logo: "https://image.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/game/163221197…",
  ...
}
```

And you want to update the document to look like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  logo: "https://cloudfront.net/prod/game/163221197…",
  ...
}
```

Then [the suggestion from @rickhg12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73982739/how-do-i-partially-update-a-field-in-mongodb-so-the-new-field-will-replace-the-o#comment130636374_73982739) is absolutely the way to go.  The `update` would use the aggregation pipeline syntax and look something like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      logo: {
        $replaceOne: {
          input: "$logo",
          find: "image.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com",
          replacement: "cloudfront.net"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nq9WujOO_d1).

It may also be worth mentioning that the wording in this question is a little misleading. You cannot "partially update" a field in MongoDB. While the intent behind the wording is to indicate that we are logically attempting to modify the existing string, this will be translated into setting a new string value for the field when the change happens on the database. This doesn't change anything about this answer, but it may be helpful information to keep in mind when thinking about the behavior of MongoDB in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Because I'm new in using MongoDB that is why I'm just using partially like just in other DB Platform.

Comment: Happy to help.  Is there anything else that I can do in this answer to help it address the original question?

Comment: Just quick question can you give advise where can I improve my skills and knowledge in MongoDB?